# Assistance with forming normal vectors on the graph

Tags: matlab

I am doing an assignment question [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJxRA.png) I am trying to find the normal vectors to my 'ice-cream' cone curve, which consists of a part cone and part sphere. I need help with the code because I cannot plot my normal vectors properly as Matlab gives me the error that "Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  3.710940e-21." and I am really not sure how to fix this. Would you please assist me with this finding a solution to this problem.

**P.S: This code below is for Q5, which requires equations for the sphere and the cone that are given in the Q4 description**.

```
u = linspace(0,2*pi,20); v = linspace(0,sqrt(2),20);

[u,v] = meshgrid(u,v);

%Parameterize the sphere

x = v.*cos(u) + 8;

y = v.*sin(u) + 5;

z = sqrt(4-v.^2)+3; 

surf(x,y,z); 

%normal vectors to the upper hemisphere

Nxs = v.*cos(u)/2;

Nys = v.*sin(u)/2;

Nzs = sqrt(4-v.^2)/2;

%Parameterize the cone

xc = v.*cos(u) + 8;

yc = v.*sin(u) + 5;

zc = 3 + v; %Subbed what xc and yc were into the zc equation:  zc = 3+sqrt((xc-8).^2+(yc-5).^2) to come up with a much more and better simplification

u1 = linspace(0,2*pi,10); v1 = linspace(pi/4,3*pi/4,10);

**%Normal Vectors to the Cone - where the error occurs**

Ncx = -v.*cos(u)/sqrt(2*v.^2+6*v.^1+9);

Ncy = -v.*sin(u)/sqrt(2*v.^2+6*v.^1+9);

Ncz = -(3+v)/sqrt(2*v.^2+6*v.^1+9);

%plotting the graph with normal vectors attached

hold on;

surf(x,y,z);

quiver3(x,y,z,Nxs,Nys,Nzs,0.5,'color','k');

surf(xc,yc,zc);

quiver3(v.*cos(u) + 8,v.*sin(u) + 5,3 + v,Ncx,Ncy,Ncz,'color','k');

xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');

hold off;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part of the code:

```
Ncx = -v.*cos(u)./sqrt(2*v.^2+6*v.^1+9);

Ncy = -v.*sin(u)./sqrt(2*v.^2+6*v.^1+9);

Ncz = -(3+v)./sqrt(2*v.^2+6*v.^1+9);
```

Explanation: you forgot to do the element-wise division when calculating the Ncx..z components. Without the dot, Matlab roughly tries to calculate `-v.*cos(u)*inv(2*v.^2+6*v.^1+9)`, so the "matrix close to singular" error appears.